# lean() no longer works when moving from stream() to cursor()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cursor

As of the DeprecationWarning added [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/4117/commits/94557653dba2cd9046f1b2ffab427cef4632a7c3), it seems to say that `cursor()` is a drop-in replacement for `stream()`, however, there is some functionality that seems to have been left behind.

For example, this deprecated code will have "lean" documents that are *not* instances of `mongoose.Document`:

```
Cat
    .find({ }).lean()
    .stream()
    .on('data', function (data) {
        var value = data instanceof mongoose.Document;
        console.log('lean().stream() data instanceof mongoose.Document', value);
    })
    .on('end', function () { });
```

and this code will have mongoose Documents, even when `lean()` is used:

```
Cat
    .find({ }).lean()
    .cursor()
    .on('data', function (data) {
        var value = data instanceof mongoose.Document;
        console.log('lean().cursor() data instanceof mongoose.Document', value);
    })
    .on('end', function () {});
```

Which is **super** strange since their source code at the time of this change looks identical:

`stream()`:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/94557653dba2cd9046f1b2ffab427cef4632a7c3/lib/query.js#L2769

`cursor()`:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/94557653dba2cd9046f1b2ffab427cef4632a7c3/lib/query.js#L2816

Is there a proper way to achieve this with `cursor()` or did I find a bug? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: The code looks the same at first glance, but `stream()` returns a `QueryStream` while `cursor()` returns a `QueryCursor`. So at least that explains why they may have different behavior.

Comment: oh thanks! This should help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found after research (and thanks to JohnnyHK's comment), looks like it wasn't implemented in `cursor()`, so I've made a pull request to fix this issue https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/4255